# Inputting arguments in plot function of R

Tags: r, function, plot, arguments

How do I plot a function which has more than one argument in R.

Suppose I have the function:

```
fn1<-function(x,y){
sin(x+y)
}
```

I want to plot the function fn1 when y=2 but plot(fn1,y=2) doesn't work. What is the correct command to do so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply apply all arguments to your defined function `fn1`, e.g.:

```
plot(fn1(x=1:100, y=2))
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you really want is to see the value of fn1 when y = 2 you should use a single argument:

```
fn1 <- function(x) {
  sin(x + 2) 
}
```

And then plot it across an index in the x that you created

```
plot(fn1(seq(0, 2 * pi, 0.2)), 1:length(fn1(seq(0, 2 * pi, 0.2))))
```

What you have now in your question is a plot function where the first argument has the function you created but no input.  And the second argument is stating that y = 2 *for the plot*.  And if you wanted to plot a vector of a length different from one, it is going to default to an index where the first argument is plotted against the order of your first argument. Hope that made sense. :)